# Calling a bootstrap modal form with action buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal form with a button to open a new window in the browser using passed parameters

Here is the call to the modal form

```
<div class='ts-1-8' onClick='showMsg($row1_desc, $row1_ref)'</div>
```

Here is the modal form

```
<div class='modal fade' id='MyModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg' role='document'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        <form>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='modal_message' class='col-form-label'>Order:</label>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary btn-xs' data-dismiss='modal'>OK</button>
            <button type='button' id='meal' class='meal btn btn-secondary btn-xs' data-dismiss='modal'>Meal Data</button>
            <textarea class='form-control' rows='19' cols='30' id='modal_message'></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
function showMsg(modal_message, ref)
{
    var win = "";
    var meal = "../command/command?ref="+ref;
    $('#MyModal .meal').click(function() {
        win = window.open(meal, '_blank');
        win.focus();
    });


    
    if (typeof modal_message !== 'undefined'){
        var message = "";
        $("#modal_message").html(modal_message);
        $('#MyModal').modal('handleUpdate');
        $('#MyModal').modal('show');
    }
}
```

The modal form pops up with the correct information.  I can open a new window when I click on the meal button and it passes the correct parameter in variable=ref.

The problem is if I do it again with different data in ref, then the new data is not used... It still remembers the old data.

btw: function showMsg is called by the onclick and then it fires again via the button(meal) in the modal form.

I tried to use jQuery to replace the first onclick but couldn't get it to work
`$(".ts-1-8").on('click', function(event){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using a hidden textarea in the modal form `<textarea class='form-control' rows='1' cols='30' id='modal_hid'></textarea>` and to reference it in the JavaScript `document.getElementById("modal_hid").value = ref;`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to clear everything you've sent to a modal window before you pass in new data. The way you do it depends on what type of elements you need to clear. Usually you just need to write another function that executes each time you close modal window, reseting it to a starting state.

Comment: Not quite, there are 2 variables sent to the modal form _italic_modal_message, ref _italic_.   modal_message is some text which works fine.  ref is the url parameter used to open a new window.  The url parameter gets passed in to the modal form, but '<button type='button' id='meal' class='meal btn btn-secondary btn-xs' data-dismiss='modal'>Evening Meal</button>' does not pick up the new ref, the second time round.

Comment: @osieman could you upload an example of your code to codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: _italic_     var win = "";
    var meal = "../command/command?ref="+ref;
    $('#MyModal .meal').click(function() {
        ref = "";
 $('#myModal').modal('hide');          
        win = window.open(meal, '_blank');
        win.focus();
    });_italic_   ... this part of the code only gets the variable (ref) on first run and uses the same value each time thereafter.

Comment: I will try to get it in jsfiddle... will need a fit of time

Comment: My first ever fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/uzbmfg7w/   It should open a google search page with param=test for button 1 and param=newtest for button 2... but it always is param=  the first one opened only

Comment: I managed to solve this using a hidden textarea in the modal form '<textarea class='form-control' rows='1' cols='30' id='modal_hid'></textarea>' and to reference it in the JavaScript     'document.getElementById("modal_hid").value = ref;'... not sure if this was the best way to do it.